Why are the equations of motion for a free quantum field theory always linear?
So far all the Lagrangians I have come across in my studying of quantum field theory have had a free theory whose equations of motion are linear. A linear free theory is of course desirable from a computational point of view so an explicit form can be found when defining propagators.
I have began to wonder if this is a coincidence or if this is by design. If it is the latter, what is the physical reason we require free theories to be linear?

What is your definition of "free theory" that could possibly include non-linear e.o.m.?

@ACuriousMind I am thinking of a free theory as any theory that describes non-interacting particles. I don't see why this definition implies the equations of motion must be linear. Or is linearity part of the definition?

If the solutions to a "free theory" did not obey the superposition principle that the sum of two solutions is still a solution (which is what linearity means), in what sense would the theory be non-interacting? A's a solution, B's a solution, but A+B isn't a solution - doesn't sound very non-interacting to me!

@ACuriousMind Thank you, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!

In principle, you could perform a nonlinear field redefinition $\eta=f(\varphi)$   ($f$ is some invertible function) without changing the physics. In other words, a noninteracting theory remains noninteracting in spite of a more complicated looking Lagrangian. An elementary discussion can be found in the book by A. Zee, Quantum field theory in a nutshell, 2nd ed., pp. 68-69.


Why are the equations of motion for a free quantum field theory always linear?

"Free field theory" and "field theory with linear equations of motions" are two different terms that mean the same thing. This is like asking why "cheerful" people are always "happy." Cheerful and happy are just synonyms. There is no deeper underlying reason.
See, for example, the Wikipedia article titled "Free field," which reads, in part:

"In classical physics, a free field is a field whose equations of motion are given by linear partial differential equations."

To quibble with this explanation-by-definition would seemingly require postulating an alternative definition for "free field theory," which OP has not done.

A free theory might have a lagrangian that looks like:
$$
L=(\partial \phi)^2 - m^2\phi^2
$$
or maybe it looks like:
$$
L=(\partial \phi)^2 - m^2\phi^2 - V(x)\phi^2\;,
$$
for a non-dynamical field $V(x)$ (not a function of $\phi$), where $V(x)$ is a called a potential term (not an interaction term).
In either of the above cases the resulting equations of motion are linear, a la:
$$
\partial^2\phi(x) - m^2\phi(x) - V(x)\phi(x) = 0\;, \tag{1}
$$
such that if $\phi_1$ is a solution to Eq.(1) and $\phi_2$ is a solution to Eq. (1) then so to is $a\phi_1 + b\phi_2$.

We can also add a source term like $\phi(x)j(x)$ and we continue to call the field theory "free" as long as $j(x)$ is just a background field that doesn't depend on other dynamical fields. We refer to a term like $j(x)$ as a "source term." In this case the equations of motions look like:
$$
\partial^2\phi(x) - m^2\phi(x) - V(x)\phi(x) = j(x)\;,
$$
which is still call a linear equation of motion since it is a linear differential equation.

Thank you for your answer. I think a better way to phrase my question is why is a free field defined that way? For example, what prohibits the dynamics of a free/non-interacting particle from being described by a nonlinear PDE?
